# How to display arrow in button? Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do I get this type of arrow in button as shown in [this image link](http://s16.postimg.org/rr0kuocqp/Screen_Shot_2015_06_01_at_10_43_15_pm.png).

I need to get this type of arrow for UP, DOWN, LEFT and RIGHT.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a button with no text and set the image property to an image of an arrow.
You can use this image (just rotate it to any direction you need)

[image]

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can also do that using  UTF32 characters values :

```
  Button1.Text = char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x2193);
  Button2.Text = char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x2191);
```

Gives :[image]

You cal use bold in the font if you want.

Have a look to [U+2190](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrows_(Unicode_block)) in [List of Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)

Comment: i tried setting the text of a button in vb.net like so `btn.Text = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(&H23F4)`, but it does shows a box icon, indicating that, usually displayed for unknown character

Comment: 0x23F4 is supposed to be the BLACK MEDIUM LEFT-POINTING TRIANGLE. It's suppose to work. I'll have a try.